# Conditional stylesheets. I need to style according IE versions and having

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements, stylesheet, detect

Hi,
I wrote a condition stylesheet, and I couldn't find condition for **IE7-IE7.9**

I wrote these:

• equal to IE6 or less than IE6 .. => [if lte IE 6]

• IE7-IE7.9 .. => [??]

• equal to IE8 and greater than IE8 (meaning IE8-IE8.9, IE9, IE10..).. => [if gte IE 8]

So, I can't find condition for **IE7-IE7.9** 
I need to detect IE7 and it's higher version till 7.9.

What was your solution in this kind of problem?

My last code looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="template_style.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[??]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up-till-ie7.9.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use classes to cope with the conditional IE styling-:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->
```

In the example above the classes `ie7` `lte8` are set if IE7 is used.

Comment: but my html element already fill with class "no-js" of Modernizr...
`<html class="no-js">`